# Android sqlite database error SQLiteException no such column

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

When opening my activity where my database is being created, it immediately crashes with the error SQLiteException: no such column. I'm stumped on what to do as SQLite is still very much a mystery to me.

****New error, this time I can create the workout note, but once I click to edit it, I get another no such column exists, this time squatLabel. But it does exist....****

Edit: The only error I am getting at this point is the no such column exists: squatLabel

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;

public class WorkoutList extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private StrongDbAdapter mDbHelper;


    /** Called when the 5x5 button is pressed in first activity */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.workout_list);
        mDbHelper = new StrongDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor NotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();

        // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
        NotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(NotesCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{StrongDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.workout_row };

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.workout_row, NotesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case INSERT_ID:
                createNote();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNote() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WorkoutEdit.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, WorkoutEdit.class);
        i.putExtra(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);

        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }
}
```

Here is some of my WorkoutEdit class where problems seem to be happening.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class WorkoutEdit extends Activity {

    public TextView mTitleText;
    //private EditText mBodyText;
    private Long mRowId;
    private StrongDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    public TextView squats;
    public boolean workoutA;
    public String workoutState;
    //private double rowId = mRowId;
    public String squatLabel;
    public Button confirmButton;
    private Long prevId ;





    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(note);
            //mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                    //note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            workoutState=(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            squats.setText(note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(StrongDbAdapter.SQUAT_LABEL)));
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(StrongDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
    }



    //Saves all the data to the database
    private void saveState() {
        String title = workoutState;
        String squatLabel = squats.getText().toString();


        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, squatLabel);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title);
        }
    }       

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }

    }



}
```

And here is my DbAdapter

****Updated Create Statement****

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class StrongDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";


    public static final String WORKOUT_STATE = "workoutState";

    public static final String SQUAT_LABEL = "squatLabel";

    private static final String TAG = "StrongDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;



    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement , "
        + "title text," +
        " squatLabel text, workoutState text );";


    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public StrongDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public StrongDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }



    public long createNote(String title, String squatLabel) {


        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        //initialValues.put(WORKOUT_STATE, workoutState);
        initialValues.put(SQUAT_LABEL, squatLabel);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the note with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                WORKOUT_STATE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, WORKOUT_STATE}, KEY_ROWID + "='" + rowId+"'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
     * values passed in
     * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        //args.put(WORKOUT_STATE, workoutState);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

And finally my LogCat:

****With new create statement, this time no such column squatLabel.****

```
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts/com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts.WorkoutEdit}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'squatLabel' does not exist
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'squatLabel' does not exist
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:301)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts.WorkoutEdit.populateFields(WorkoutEdit.java:199)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts.WorkoutEdit.onCreate(WorkoutEdit.java:82)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
08-05 18:57:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: After you modify your 'create' string, you will need to do one of two things. Either increment `DATABASE_VERSION` to force  `onUpgrade(...)` to be called or go to Manage Applications and Clear Data to delete the current DB to force `onCreate(...)` to be called again.

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! However I'm getting more errors but at least its a start.

Comment: Please, look at my updated answer. It looks like You did not add the SQUAT_LABEL field to the db.query() method's parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that your updated Create DB statement is correct.

As regards to the next error: it seams that You never close your database and cursor.
I usually use the next template when work with DB:

```
openReadableDatabase(); // or openWritableDatabase();

// do some work with DB

closeDatabase();
```

Aforementioned methods may look like:

```
private void closeDatabase() {
    if (_db != null && _db.isOpen()) {
        _db.close();
    }
}

private void openReadableDatabase() {
    _db = getReadableDatabase();
}

private void openWritableDatabase() {
    _db = getWritableDatabase();
}
```

The same You can apply to the cursor object:

```
Cursor cursor = _db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null, null, null);

// do some work with cursor

cursor.close();
```

FROM is a array of column names. Notice: the comma after the last column name is not a typo.

```
private static final String[] FROM = { COLUMN1_NAME, COLUMN2_NAME, };
```

**Updated:**
You should add a SquatLabel column to the data retrieving parameter in the db.query() method (and the same for the fetchNote method):

```
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
        SQUAT_LABEL, WORKOUT_STATE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a method that closes the DbHelper and got rid of the error. Now I'm just stuck with this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'squatLabel' does not exist

Comment: Look at the updated answer. You should add a squat label column to the columns parameter in the db.query() method.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you don't have that column defined in your DB.

What they've neglected to tell you is that you must do one of two things **after** you add the column to your db schema in the app.

1) Delete and re-install your app, so the new schema for the DB gets used when the DB is created

or

2) Increment the version of your database so that the onUpgrade method gets called and updates your DB to the new schema

Comment: Crud, just realized Squonk pointed this out an hour ago in comments.  Well, as no one has added it to their answer, I'll leave this here until someone does.  (I hate having to go into comments to find the full/complete answer).

Comment: Thanks anyways! I fixed my first column error, but now I am getting it again but with no such column: squatLabel, even though it's in my create statement and I have cleared the database data/restalled my app many times.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your create statement:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement , "
        + "title text," +
        " squatLabel text );";
```

You don't have `workoutState` included. Simply add the column into the create statement.

Comment: @user1576752 I find it hard to believe that it gives the exact same erorr. You should also update your question with the correct create statement. You should also run it again with the correct statement and see if it really gives you the exact same error.

Comment: I updated the statement and the log, it looks quite similar if not the same error message to me

Comment: @Recursed : See my comment on the OP's question. Simply modifying the create statement won't fix things unless the original DB is deleted or the version number is incremented to force an upgrade. It's a quirk of how the Android `SQLiteOpenHelper` class works. Your answer is effectively correct of course - it just required an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing the same error, if you're querying a string make sure you add quotations.

Example, I had in error when I wrote like this:

```
        Cursor cursor = this.database.query(
            SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{ID, FNAME},
            "fname"+" = "+name,   ......
```

I solved it by:

```
        Cursor cursor = this.database.query(
            SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{ID, FNAME},
            "fname"+" = "+"'"+name+"'", .....
```